# save the params hash into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i have very simple newbie questions params hashs here, this is the following code of params hash from my view,

```
{ name: 'name supplier',
  fax: 'fax supplier',
  contact_persons: [
  {name: 'contact person 1', value_number: '123456', value_type: 'mobile phone'},
  {name: 'contact person 2', value_number: '123456', value_type: 'mobile phone'},
  {name: 'contact person 3', value_number: '123456', value_type: 'email'},
  {name: 'contact person 4', value_number: '123456', value_type: 'bb'}
  ]
}
```

i want to save it on db, but how i do that, its not just simple ContactPerson.new(params[:contat_persons]) right??

Comment: Can you send view and controller of ContactPerson?

Comment: i dont use view because i am use only JSON for this, and i use other common controller, is that a problem??
do whatever it takes, i just know how to do that, no matter the way is, if necessary use your own example please,

Comment: With any views, you have to post the form to rails controller and then rails controller save data to database and also type of json that you send to server, is important.

Comment: the view is worked by different person in my case, i only got the params from output form like code above, and i have to save the entire params to respective table

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a has_many relationship between your Supplier and ContactPerson you could do something from supplier.rb like:

```
params[:contact_persons].each { |person| contact_persons.build(person) }
contact_persons.save
```